# Bash - How to get data from a file only from row after row 5-20?

Tags: bash

How to get data from a file only from row after row 5-20 ?

```
while IFS=';' read col1 col2 col3
do
    echo "$col1 $col2 $col3"
done < myfile.csv
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This is tailor-made job for `awk`:

```
awk -F';' 'NR>=5 && NR<=20{print $1, $2, $3}' file.csv
```

Comment: You are getting each line separately in awk. Of course it can be done using bash for loop and using a counter but awk is better tool for processing data line by line

Answer (score 2):

With sed:

```
sed -n '5,20p;21q' < myfile.csv
```

This suppresses output (`-n`), explicitly prints lines 5 to 20, then quits on line 21. The last part is not really required, but prevents sed from going through the rest of the file for nothing.

This just prints complete lines, as you're doing in your example; if you want to do some processing, sed quickly becomes cumbersome.

Answer (score -1):

use `head` and `tail`:

```
#!/bin/bash

STARTL=5
ENDL=20

tail -n +"${STARTL}" myfile.csv |
head -n "$((${ENDL} +1 -${STARTL}))" |
while IFS=';' read col1 col2 col3
do
    echo "$col1 $col2 $col3"
done; 3<&0
```

**EDIT**

As reported by *Benjamin W.* the solution above may prevent variable sharing as the while loop is executed in a new subshell with its own copy of variables. In this particular case it is working since we just `echo` variables defined in the while loop.

A better way to go is to use *ProcessSubstitution*:

```
#!/bin/bash

STARTL=5
ENDL=20

while IFS=';' read col1 col2 col3
do
    echo "$col1 $col2 $col3"
done < <(tail -n +"${STARTL}" myfile.csv |
head -n "$((${ENDL} +1 -${STARTL}))")
```

Comment: Thank you, syntax error near unexpected token `tail' :-(

Comment: `done < <(myfile.csv tail -n +"5" | head -n "$((20 - 5))")`?

Comment: You don't need to escape newlines after pipes, and this now potentially suffers from "piping into a while loop (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024). My process substitution still stands as a recommendation ;)

Comment: Interesting. Thx for pinpointing this potential issue! I edited my answer.